# Date and Time Not inserting into the database in android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date, time

I am trying to insert the current system date and time into table as an entry.But  it not getting inserted.

It shows the error:
near ":05": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT into calories values( 10, 21:05 , 2018-05-30);

Code for the date and date and time function is as follows:

```
 String FetchTime()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());
            return time;
    }
    String FetchDate()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(new Date());
        return date;
    }
```

code for fetching date and time and putting them into the table:

```
                time=FetchTime();
                date=FetchDate();
                System.out.println( time+"  <-->  "+date);
                String insert_stmt="INSERT into "+ msg.toString()+" values( "+ Integer.parseInt(msg1)+", "+time+" , " + date+");";
                SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.execSQL(insert_stmt);
```

Code for Creation of table:

```
//create table
        SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String create_table="create table "+ txt.toString()+"(mvalue INTEGER, mtime varchar(20),mdate varchar(20) ); ";
        db.execSQL(create_table);
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM") is wrong: M stands for month not minute. Change to "HH:mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use timestamp instead of date and time

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```